# How to make navigation drawer opened 1/3 of the screen in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have a listview with navigation drawer, what I want to make drawer opened 1/3 rd of the screen by default and will open in full when user slide. How do I do that

Answer (score 0):

values\dimens.xml

```
    <resources>
   <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
   <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
   <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="navigation_drawer_width">250dp</dimen>

   </resorces>
```

In xml define navigationView

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_actual_home"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_actual_home_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the width of the display and set the width for you navigation drawer

```
Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int displayWidth = size.x;
int displayHeight = size.y;
```

set drawer width

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = drawer.getLayoutParams()
params.width = displayWidth / 3; //calculates 1/3 of the screen width
drawer.setLayoutParams(params);
```